# How to make a search box that looks like this

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

[image]

This is simply not how standard search bar look like. How do I make one like this? Should use UITextField instead? Should I use a label on the left and a UITextField on the fight? Can I still use searchController if I use UITextField instead of searchController?

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom view.

You have to use a UITextField and a UILabel and some images or [QuartzCore](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/QuartzCoreRefCollection/_index.html) for shadows and background.